# Mount on Windows for RHL

Tags: windows, mount, rhel

I have a folder on my Windows 2012 R2 Server.
I want to mount that folder to different RHEL Box.

How can I do that. DO i need any 3rd Party software to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Samba or CIFS, [start here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Managing_Confined_Services/chap-Managing_Confined_Services-Samba.html):

Here is the [samba ref guide](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/)
You will also see some stuff about CIFS, which a compatible protocol.

This should allow you to do all that you're asking and more.  You'll only need the samba client stuff to mount a Windows share on a RHEL box.

Answer (score 0):

Seem this link will , windows shares a know n as SMB share or similar 
 to CIFS

http://www.linuxnix.com/2009/09/8-ways-to-mount-smbfs-samba-file-system-in-linux.html